# Nondeterministic foreach on Stream class, Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

The Java docs says about the method forEach on Stream class:

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic.

So what I understand is that It could be possible to have different outcomes from repeated sequential (and so not parallel) executions of identical stream pipelines on an identical source even if the source has an encouter order. Is that right? Could someone give me an example to illustrate that?

Comment: Probably if you want the same output order you should use `forEachOrdered` instead of `forEach`. Cool question tho !

Comment: There is no example as the *current implementation* does not exploit this opportunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements inside pipeline may be processed in parallel manner (see [Parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) entry) independently to each other so the intermediate operations made made the individual elements may vary - hence the order is not predictable in case the terminal operation is invoked on the stream working in parallel mode.

It may also depend on the data source the stream originates from (be it `HashSet` for instance) and the intermediate operations in between - see [Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) entry.

Check if any intermediate operation introduces parallelism `myStream.isParallel() == true` or breaks ordering `myStream.unordered()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @dawid gdanski.
What is odd for me is that the javadoc says that forEach is explicitly nondeterministic. I understood it is nondeterministic even for non parallel and ordered stream, what I found wierd.

Comment: @BrunoBravo your understanding is correct. Keep in mind that you can always call `unordered()` on a stream which also is releasing the ordering contract, regardless of whether the stream is sequential or parallel.